# Dimension of the Steinberg representation of $GL_n(\mathbb F_q)$

Tags: representation-theory

I have a question about the Steinberg representation of $G:=GL_n(\mathbb F_q).$ My definition here is via the Hecke algebra $\mathcal H$ over the complete flags on an $n$-dimensional $\mathbb F_q$-vector space $V.$ If we let $\mathcal B$ be the space of complete flags on $V,$ and $\mathcal F$ the space of all $\mathbb C$-valued function on $\mathcal B,$ then we can view each $T\in \mathcal H$ as a $G$-invariant endomorphism on $\mathcal F,$ by defining
$$Tf\colon B\in\mathcal B\mapsto\sum_{B'\in\mathcal B}T(B,B')f(B').$$
Remember the Hecke algebra admits a standard basis $\{T_{s_i}\},$ where $s_i\in S_n$ exchanges $i$ and $i+1$ and fix the others. Then we can define a $G$-invariant subspace
$$\Sigma:=\{f\in\mathcal F\vert (T_{s_i}+1)f=0\text{ for all }i\},$$
which defines the Steinberg representation.

My question is: Is there any simple way to find out the dimension of this representation?

The only way I know is to establish an isomorphism
$$\Sigma\simeq \{\text{all functions }\mathcal B_*\to\mathbb C\},$$
where
$$\mathcal B_*:=\{B\in\mathcal B\vert B\stackrel {w_0}\sim B_0\}$$
for any fixed element $B_0\in\mathcal B,$ and $w_0\in S_n$ sends $i$ to $n+1-i.$ If this isomorphism is established, then we could derive
$$\dim\Sigma=\dim \{\text{all functions }\mathcal B_*\to\mathbb C\}=q^\binom n2.$$
However, to my knowledge, the isomorphism is not easy to find out.

Any comments or ideas are appreciated!